# How can I set "allowDiskUse" option in aggregation method

Tags: php, mongodb

How can I set `allowDiskUse` option in aggregation method in PHP?
I have tried the following without any success:

```
$out = $dbnew->$a->aggregate(
  array('$match' => $filter_array),
  array('$sort' => $sorting),
  array('$skip' => $start),
  array('$allowDiskUse' => true));
```

Comment: Only in newer versions of PHP driver: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php else you would have to use db->command() manually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are providing options in a wrong place. You need to use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php):

```
public array MongoCollection::aggregate ( array $pipeline [, array $options ] )
```

and you are providing all the pipeline as a list of arrays, thus doing:

```
public array MongoCollection::aggregate ( array $op [, array $op [, array $... ]] )
```

Take in mind that you need at least **1.5.0** version of PHP driver.

So define you pipeline and options:

```
$pipeline = array(
    array('$match' => $filter_array),
    array('$sort' => $sorting),
    ...
);

$options = array("allowDiskUse" => true);
```

and use it:

```
$out = $dbnew->$a->aggregate($pipeline, $options);
```